# Do you think we need moderators from different time zones?

Tags: discussion

I notice that the site lacks any moderation at day time (GMT+3), even though I am not particularly a high scorer and consider myself a hobbyist. I feel I am one of the few people who are active during the day (GMT+3) and trying to help flag questions, do you think the site needs a moderator from the "Eastern" part of the earth [GMT, GMT+3 ] since most of the moderators seem to be living in Pacific time-zones ?

Do you think more active moderation will help GDSE get more traffic?

Comment: Aren't most of the mods eastern?

Comment: well not what I noticed, at least from what I know most of them are based in the US.

Comment: We're currently all US based. With two of us being in GMT+8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our average flag handling time is less than two hours (down from several hours since our recent election).

I think we currently have more than enough coverage in terms of moderators and high-ranking users to maintain the status quo in terms of quality. I don't see how adding more diamond moderators would improve site quality any, and I certainly don't think there will be a traffic correlation.

Note, too, that moderators are not appointed (except for the beta moderator, I think, but that's irrelevant here). Moderators are *elected*, which means that even if we thought there was a need for more diamonds, we could not guarantee that the new diamonds would be from a particular geographic region.

Answer (score 3):

Active moderation won't get more traffic, it'll get rid of bad questions/spam...promoting will get us more traffic.

I personally don't see the need unless the problem demands it. And i don't think there is such a problem that calls for it either.

If a flag takes a few hours to be dealt with its not that bad.

...At least not for now.